# WooCommerce get products based on specific taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

I need to modify the WooCommerce product query because I want to filter the shown products on the shop pages based on product tag custom taxonomy.

So what I've tried is this here but it don't works:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_meta_query', 'filter', 10, 2 );
function filter( $meta_query, $query ) {
    // Only on category pages
    if ( ! is_product_category() ) {
        return $meta_query;
    }

    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key'     => 'taxonomy',
        'value'   => 'product_tag',
        'compare' => 'EXIST'
    );

    return $meta_query;
}
```

So I just want to display all products which have the taxonomy ABCSD in it.
The code is placed in my functions.php. What I'm doing wrong here?

**Notice:**

I mean the values I get when I call this function:

```
wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, 'product_tag' );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is about a taxonomy, you need to use a tax query and then the hook will be different. Also you can make it for specific product tags:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_tax_query', 'filter_products_with_specific_product_tags', 10, 2 );
function filter_products_with_specific_product_tags( $tax_query, $query ) {
    // Only on category pages
    if ( ! is_product_category() ) 
        return $tax_query;

    $tax_query[] = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
        'field' => 'name',
        'terms' => array('Green', 'Yellow', 'Red'), // Defined product tags term names
    );
    return $tax_query;
};
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!